# AEM - Sling Page object inconsistency

Tags: aem, sling

We are observing problems while retrieving path from the page object [com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page]. For one particular page we are not able to fetch the shortened path.

We have developed a custom breadcrumb component and the component consumes a sling model which returns a list [java.util.list] of page objects. The component works perfectly fine in most of the pages but in certain pages the component resolves to full path instead of shortened path for a particular page. We do not suspect anything difference for that particular page's properties.

Any leads are welcome.

TIA.

Comment: Some ideas: do you have any http mappings defined under /etc/map? Also try the URL at /system/console/servletresolver and see what servlet is resolving the different pages to see if there is something different in how they are handled.

Comment: Just a guess: Could it be, that a page without page-content is in the path above? This happens, if a page is published, but the parent page was not published yet. Then only the cq:Page node of the parent page is created automatically, but not the jcr:content node below this parent page. This would prevent the reverse path mapping (as the sling:alias is missing).